# pm2 + KOA process.send is undefined

Tags: node.js, process, pm2, koa2

I am trying to accomplish the "graceful start" with pm2, but somehow my process.send is always undefined.

I am using **esm** module and start my application with **yarn start**

I am logging the process.send, but somehow it is always undefined.

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('process.send', process.send);
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Where could be the problem?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: how pm2 is configured?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon 

module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'myApp',
    script: 'yarn',
    args: 'start',
    interpreter: '/bin/bash',
    time: true,
    listen_timeout: 10000,
    env: {
      environment: 'production',
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
    },
  }],
};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with an application using `npm start` as script in **pm2**.

I guess **pm2** needs to start the application with an internal child process in **node** to make `process.send('ready')` work.

Changing to `"script": "./dist/main.js"` for **pm2** made it work for me.

So maybe changing your config and application to something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'myApp',
      script: './dist/main.js',
      time: true,
      listen_timeout: 10000,
      env: { environment: 'production', NODE_ENV: 'production', },
    }
  ],
};
```

(Depending of the output from your build)

Comment: Thanks, I will check this solution. I am using ```yarn``` thats why I am not sure if it will work.